# How do I pre-populate my selectbox with current ID in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a select box in my form where I can choose a user from a list. This saves correctly and applies the user to my Chasing model, but I'm wondering if it's possible to have the select show the currently assigned user instead of having it reset every time I edit the object. My form code is:

```
<%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(User.all.map {|c| [c.name, c.id]}), { :include_blank => "Please select user"}, {:class => "form-control"} %>
```

I've also made it so that the form needs the presence of user to be saved, however there may be occasions where I need to save a new Chasing with a default user (called 'Unassigned'). Is there a way of defaulting the select box to this user **unless** the Chasing already has a user assigned to it?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `@object.field_name` in `options_for_select` after `collection` as below.

```
<%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(User.all.map {|c| [c.name, c.id]}, @object.user_id), { :include_blank => "Please select user"}, {:class => "form-control"} %>
```

Hope this will fix you issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to this: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

```
<%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(User.all.map {|c| [c.name, c.id]}, current_user.id), { :include_blank => "Please select user"}, {:class => "form-control"} %>
```

(replace `current_user` with your user object you want to place in)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `:selected => value` as param

```
<%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(User.all.map {|c| [c.name, c.id]}), { :include_blank => "Please select user"}, {:class => "form-control", :selected => o.customer_id }  %>
```

Comment: I recommend using the parameter in `options_for_select`